# In fancyhdr : change the height of a logo in the footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, height

I want to put the logo of my school in the bottom right of my pages. The problem is that the logo collides with the text on top.
I know that the position of the footer is ruled by the `\footskip` command, but the position of the footer is not the problem. The problem is that the bottom of the logo is aligned with the bottom of the box of the footer. 
I would like to align the top of the logo with the top of the box. I already tried to put a `\vspace{}` but it doesn't follow the values I put inside. My code is

`\rfoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{logo.jpg}}`

But

`\rfoot{\vspace{5pt}\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{logo.jpg}}`

shifts the logo in the bottom, yes, but whatever value I put in the `\vspace{}` command, the result is always the same, i.e. the logo does shift, but the value is not respected.

What could I do ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `\raisebox` and hide the height and depth of the image. Schematically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=0.10]{example-image-a}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Change `-\height` to the desired value. Notice also that it's better to use the modern `\fancyfoot[]{}` syntax than the old `\rfoot{}`. The `showframe` package was only used to have a visual guide for the page layout.

Comment: Awesome ! I can finally shift my logo. But I don't understand what the two `[0pt]` stand for ? Is it the hiding of the depth and height of the image ? What is that ?
Now I see that my logo is just a bit on the right, is there a way to correct that ? I tried using the `[0pt]` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Darryl The two optional arguments control the height and depth of the box (the image, in your case to be raised. Setting them to `0pt` tricks TeX into thinking that the image has zero depth and height, so you can freely move it vertically. Regarding the "just a bit on the right", part, impossible to tell without seeing your actual code. In any case, as I explained, the optional arguments won't be of use for horizontal shiftings. You can always open a follow-up question.

Comment: Hehe, got it. I used the function `\setmarginsrb{30mm}{8mm}{31mm}{15mm}{1cm}{5mm}{1mm}{10mm}` and replaced the third value by something else. It's stange, though, because changing this third value only moves the right footer, not the text. The first value which controls the left margin works perfectly fine (the text and the footer follow it). Bit of a hack, but oh well. I have to deal with this right margin now. 
For me my question is answered. Thx again !

Comment: @Darryl You're welcome! To change margins in your document and, in general, the page layout, the recommended way is through the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.